# How to reset Hystrix Circuit Breaker completely before every unit tests?

Tags: kotlin, hystrix, netflix

I have some test cases, and also have a test where i want to test that CB get triggered. But every time i run the tests, sometimes it fails, some times it passed. I understand that i need to reset hystrix, but how can i do that? Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had some issues with this myself.

Using `Hystrix.reset()` by itself didn't work when resetting Circuit Breakers.
The following method is working for me.

```
private void resetCircuitBreakers() {
    Hystrix.reset();
    HealthCountsStream.reset();
}
```